# JavaScript arithmetic operations between strings of numbers

Tags: javascript, string, math

I'm wondering what happens behind the scenes when we either add, subtract or multiply two strings of numbers. Here is an example:

```
let strNum1 = "300";
let strNum2 = "22";

let multiply = function(num1, num2) {
    let product = num1 * num2;
    
    return `${product}`
      
};

multiply(strNum1, strNum2); //this will return ==> "6600"
```

Does the JS engine turns these into integers first and then performs the operations or does it know "magically" that they are numbers even though it's in a string form? The reason I'm asking is because of the [long multiplication algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication). For numbers bigger than 8 chars it becomes funky when multiplying with the operator vs using the algorithm.

This is a [leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/multiply-strings) btw.

Comment: It attempts to convert the strings to numbers first.

Comment: The `*` operator coerces the strings into numbers, that'll happen with `-`, `/` ,`%`, etc. `+` is the exception it'll be interpreted as concatenating of two strings. You can still use `+` to coerce string into number by enclosing the right side string in parenthesis: `"1" +(+"2")`

Comment: @habibg I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that ? I hope that will help you in understanding the use case and will work as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In case of addition (`+`), When a number is added to a string, JavaScript converts the number to a string before concatenation but in case of other arithmetic operations like `*`, `-`, `/` JS engine implicitly convert the string into integer.

Demo **:**

```js
let result;

// numeric string used with + gives string type

result = '3' + '2'; 
console.log(result, typeof result) // "32", "string"

// numeric string used with - , / , * results number type

result = '3' * '2'; 
console.log(result, typeof result) // 6, "number"

result = '3' - '2'; 
console.log(result, typeof result) // 1, "number"

result = '3' / '2'; 
console.log(result, typeof result) // 1.5, "number"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your values before and after operation:

```js
let multiply = function(num1 = '', num2 = '') {
    const product = Number(num1) * Number(num2);
    
    return `${product}` // Or String(product)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: The JS Engine turns those strings into integers before doing the arithmetic operation. It is called `Implicit coercion`.

You can read more about that in this [You Don't Know JS Chapter](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html#:%7E:text=explicit%20coercion%20options.-,Implicit%20Coercion,-Implicit%20coercion%20refers).